# Mocking method returning java.util.List using mockito in scala

Tags: scala, mockito

I would like to return java.util.List

```
  val cacheManager = mock(classOf[CacheManager])
  val cache = mock(classOf[Cache])

  when(cacheManager.getCache(anyString)).thenReturn(cache)
  when(cache.getKeys.asInstanceOf[List[String]]).thenReturn(List("some_key"))
```

It compiles, but throws:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
  at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.checkStatus(Cache.java:2722)
  at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.getKeys(Cache.java:1912)
  at (last line of code)
```

How can I fix it? I tried a couple of ways, but without a success.

Method signature:

```
     public final java.util.List getKeys() throws java.lang.IllegalStateException, net.sf.ehcache.CacheException { /* compiled code */ }
```

Comment: Eh, mockito can't mock final methods and that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerMock, an extension to Mockito and other, however can mock final methods. http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockFinal

Also when referring to java.util.List you probably want to use the full name and not just List, which normally is scala.collection.immutable.List.